# Compulsory information to create CustomerProfile at Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am developing service for payment integration in C#. I am creating CustomerProfile at Authorize.net. We are asking user to enter his name,address,email,mobile no, credit card number, expirydate and cvv no only.

So I just want to know what are the compulsory information that I need to provide to Authorize.net to create CustomerProfile?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a customer profile, [you must have the following](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile):

- merchantCustomerID OR
- description OR
- email (except in Europe where email is required)

You can see an example here: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-CreateCustomerProfile-Issues/m-p/53776#M28859